# How to access webpack modules from a userscript?

Tags: javascript, webpack, tampermonkey

I want to write a userscript (for TamperMonkey et al) for a website that instead of any sane method, uses webpack to bundle/load JS libraries. I need to tinker with one of those libraries. They not on the global namespace as usual, so where are they?

Note that while there are similar questions here on SO, they are from a developer's perspective and boil down to "change the code" or "change the webpack config", both of which I can't do.

Comment: Usually code that's bundled with Webpack doesn't expose the modules used to develop the app on Window or anywhere else, unless there's a specific need to (for example, calling some internal analytics code from Google Tag Manager); or unless the developers writing the app that got bundled were sloppy. You're probably not going to have a whole lot of luck that way.

Comment: Ye, I get that it doesn't expose them the usual way for a reason, but I think there must be a way to dig it out